# How do I make launcher of Maple12 on my Desktop. Linux Mint

Tags: maple, linux-mint

I have recently buy and installed Maple 12 on Linux Mint. It has installed on root directory.
/root/maple12, the problem is that I don't know how to setup a launcher from the desktop.

What are all the steps do I need to follow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an empty file on your Desktop named "Mapple12.desktop" and put the following content there:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Mapple12
Icon=path_to_icon_file
Exec=path_to_execuatble_file
Type=Application
```

save and close the file.

Finally modify permission on your mapple directory to run it from desktop:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 path_to_mapple_directory
```